# Is there anyway to dynamically associate a datalist with an input in js at runtime?

Tags: javascript, html

I am unable to associate a datalist with an input using js, however I am able to if I manually add the list attribute using the document inspector in Chrome.

After doing a bit of research, I stumbled on the fact that the list property is read-only, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772937(v=vs.85).aspx. Does this mean that it is impossible to associate a datalist using js or am I using the wrong property?

I am creating my inputs and datalists dynamically at runtime as part of a javascript library I am making so I am unable to attach the datalist in the normal way.

```js
//Please open console
var myTextInput = document.getElementById('myTextInput'),
  myDataList = document.getElementById('myDataList');

myTextInput.list = 'myDataList';
console.log(myTextInput.list); //Outputs: null

myTextInput.list = myDataList.id;
console.log(myTextInput.list); //Outputs: null

myTextInput.list = myDataList;
console.log(myTextInput.list); //Outputs: null
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="myTextInput" />
  <datalist id="myDataList">
    <option value="1" />
    <option value="2" />
    <option value="3" />
  </datalist>
</form>
```

Comment: You said, "the link property is read-only". I'm guessing that's a typo and you meant the "list" property, right?

Comment: Yup, that was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setAttribute()` - works for me in Firefox and Chrome:

```
myTextInput.setAttribute('list', 'myDataList');
```

I don't know if you have jQuery available, but if you do the jQuery version would be:

```
$(myTextInput).attr('list', 'myDataList');
```

Comment: Great answer, and quick too. I'm surprised I couldn't find this anywhere when it seems like such a common use case. I wonder why they chose to make the list property read-only.

Comment: DOM elements have both attributes and properties; setting attributes using setAttribute() is quite common (and 'list' is described as an attribute), although there is some overlap in cases like the "checked" attribute on checkboxes, which becomes a property after potentially initially being set as an attribute when the page loads (which is why the more correct jQuery code for checking a checkbox is .prop('checked', true) rather than .attr('checked', true)). I agree it's confusing in this case and should have been better documented.